# Why did Rudeus decide to look for the rest of his family with his group instead of looking for them with his father?

Tags: mushoku-tensei

In episode 7th of the second season of Mushoku Tensei, Rudeus decides to look for the rest of his family with his group, instead of looking for them with his father? Why did he do so? Why didn't he join his father's group in the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rudeus promised to take Eris home, and ruijerd promised to look after them both until they made it home. If rudeus had gone with his father there would have been a lot of arguing and fighting between them due to their strained relationship. Plus, having a separate group is better as you can search multiple places/regions at the same time.